# What, if any, diseases do larder beetles carry?

Tags: entomology

I found one of these beetles on my bed as I was attempting to get in. I'm 80% sure my cat carried it in (I found it in the exact same space he had been sitting ten minutes previously).

My question is what, if any, diseases do these bugs carry? It did not bite me, though it may have bitten my cat. I'm more worried about bacteria etc that it may have carried around my bed/room. Can they transmit salmonella? Should I break out the disinfectant, or is it no big deal?

I have researched them as best I can, and I found someone noting that they *can* spread bacteria, but found nothing on how severe it is. For example, my cat obviously spreads bacteria, but I let him on my bed without worry. I have never see one of these beetles before.

I have a secondary question, if that's allowed - what are the chances it laid eggs on my bed? It was there for possibly 4-5 hours if my cat indeed carried it in. I have rodents (pets) in my room and am peripherally worried about an infestation happening.

For context, I live in the center of the UK.

Comment: Looks like you planned to put up a pic but it is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never heard of larder beetles carrying any serious diseases and chances are slim that it could have laid any eggs, so you probably have nothing to worry about. If you want you can spray the area down with a cleaner, but as I said earlier, it's probably fine.